# Fill NaN's within 1 column of a df via lookup to another df via pandas

Tags: pandas, numpy, dataframe, missing-data, fillna

I seen various versions of this question but none of them seem to fit with what I am attempting to do: here's my data:

Here's the df with the `NaN`s:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": ["10023", "10040", np.nan, "12345", np.nan, np.nan, "10033", np.nan, np.nan],
               "B": [",", "17,-6", "19,-2", "17,-5", "37,-5", ",", "9,-10", "19,-2", "2,-5"],
               "C": ["small", "large", "large", "small", "small", "large", "small", "small", "large"]})

       A      B      C
0  10023      ,  small
1  10040  17,-6  large
2    NaN  19,-2  large
3  12345  17,-5  small
4    NaN  37,-5  small
5    NaN      ,  large
6  10033  9,-10  small
7    NaN  19,-2  small
8    NaN   2,-5  large
```

Next I have the lookup df called `df2`:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"B": ['17,-5', '19,-2', '37,-5', '9,-10'],
                "A": ["10040", "54321", "12345", "10033"]})

       B      A
0  17,-5  10040
1  19,-2  54321
2  37,-5  12345
3  9,-10  10033
```

I would like to fill in the `NaN`s of column `A` on `df` by looking up column `df2.B` and returning `df2.A` such that the resulting `dfr` looks like this:

```
       A      B      C
0  10023      ,  small
1  10040  17,-6  large
2  54321  19,-2  large
3  10040  17,-5  small
4  12345  37,-5  small
5    NaN      ,  large
6  10033  9,-10  small
7  54321  19,-2  small
8    NaN   2,-5  large
```

Important caveats:

1. The `df`s do not have matching indexes
2. The contents of `df.A` and `df2.A` are non-unique()
3. The rows of `df2` do make up unique pairs.
4. Assume that there are more columns, not shown, with `NaN`s.

Using pandas, the rows of interest on `df` would be found (I think) via: `df.loc[df['A'].isnull(),]`.   [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29293369/pandas-fillna-with-a-lookup-table) answer seemed promising but I'm unclear where `df1` in that example comes from.  My actual data set is much, much larger than this and I'll have to be doing replacing several columns in this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just using `np.where`

```
df.A=np.where(df.A.isnull(),df.B.map(df2.set_index('B').A),df.A)
df
Out[149]: 
       A      B      C
0  10023      ,  small
1  10040  17,-6  large
2  54321  19,-2  large
3  12345  17,-5  small
4  12345  37,-5  small
5    NaN      ,  large
6  10033  9,-10  small
7  54321  19,-2  small
8    NaN   2,-5  large
```

Answer (score 1):

The `map` method from Wen-Ben will be faster in terms of speed, but here's another way you can solve this problem, just for your convenience and knowledge

You can use `pd.merge`, because this is basically a `join` problem.
After the merge, we fillna and drop the columns we dont need.

```
df_final = pd.merge(df, df2, on='B', how='left', suffixes=['_1','_2'])
df_final['A'] = df_final.A_1.fillna(df_final.A_2)
df_final.drop(['A_1', 'A_2'], axis=1, inplace=True)

print(df_final)
       B      C      A
0      ,  small  10023
1  17,-6  large  10040
2  19,-2  large  54321
3  17,-5  small  12345
4  37,-5  small  12345
5      ,  large    NaN
6  9,-10  small  10033
7  19,-2  small  54321
8   2,-5  large    NaN
```

Comment: thank you - I was working on a `merge` version, too but I also saw the `map` was speedy.  Good lookin' out.

Comment: No problem, for any questions, please ask :)

Comment: btw @jmb277 if you really want to understand `merging` in depth. This post is perfect for that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101